# Наследование python

Tags: python

Ребят, подскажите пожалуйста, как унаследовать от `def index`, чтобы не повторять лишний код в `def menu`?

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    name = 'Вхід'
    if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
        name = 'Кабінет' + ' ' + current_user.login
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)

@app.route('/menu')
def menu():
    name = 'Вхід'
    if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
        name = 'Кабінет' + ' ' + current_user.login
    return  render_template('project_templates/menu.html', name=name)
```

Comment: Вынести в отдельную функцию и вызывать её

Answer (score 1):

```
def common_args():
    name = 'Вхід'
    if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
        name = 'Кабінет' + ' ' + current_user.login
    return {'name': name}

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', **common_args())

@app.route('/menu')
def menu():
    return render_template('project_templates/menu.html', **common_args())
```

Comment: Спасибо,разобрался)

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать функцию `index` с параметром и таким образом её можно будет использовать вместо `menu`

```
def index(my_html):
    name = 'Вхід'
    if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
        name = 'Кабінет' + ' ' + current_user.login
    return render_template(my_html, name=name)
```

Comment: Боюсь, такое решение будет очень плохо расширяться и кроме как в этом примере не поможет

Comment: Это простое "в лоб". Думаете стоит удалить?

Answer (score 0):

Вот такую сделал функцию,думаю нормальная, как думаете?

```
def repeat():
    name = 'Вхід'
    if login.current_user.is_authenticated:
        name = 'Кабінет' + ' ' + current_user.login
    return (name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def current_name(fn):
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['name'] = 'Кабінет %s' % current_user.login if login.current_user.is_authenticated else 'Вхід'
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrap

@current_name
@app.route('/')
def index(name):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)

# или
@app.route('/menu')
def menu():
    return current_name(render_template)('project_templates/menu.html')
```